# Simple HTTP call without opening Browser

Tags: http

Hello everybody I'm trying to do a simple HTTP call to a Tomcat Server running on my server from my Android App. The server will then execute a certain command to my website. I created a button that when I click it runs the HTTP call from the App.

**If I use the approach below, it opens the browser on my phone to run this HTTP. Is it possible to do something similar but not have my app open the browser???**

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + IP + ":8080/server/run.jsp"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

thank you so much in advance :D

Comment: Of course it's possible. Why wouldn't it be? If you had tried *anything at all*, you would have found at least three common ways for Java to access http.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a student and new to this. Please don't be mean! I wouldn't have posted if I wasn't saturated out.      I looked into using a one approach but that would of required me to use a AsyncTask which sadly I spend a while working on and couldn't get it inserted into my app. So I wanted to see if I could change the thing above and hopefully it'll work :/ but not have it open the browser.

Comment: This is the time when you actually have to do some work and learn something. If an AsyncTask (along with the many examples that are out there) is too difficult, programming might not be for you, or you would benefit from some tutoring.

Comment: "that would of required me to use a AsyncTask which sadly I spend a while working on and couldn't get it inserted into my app" -- then perhaps you should be asking questions on Stack Overflow about how to use `AsyncTask`. Or, perhaps you should use a library like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) that can make asynchronous HTTP requests without your having to fuss with an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: thank you very much let me take a look into that too (commonsWare)

Comment: So I guess answering my main question in that there is no way to use the Intent (above) but prevent it from opening the Browser in my app? If so, I guess I'll just keep  working on other approaches. Was wondering if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Of course it starts your browser.  Your code is explicitly asking Android to launch an app that can "view" the URL.

If you want your app to access the URL directly, use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead:

> 1.Obtain a new HttpURLConnection by calling URL.openConnection() and casting the result to HttpURLConnection.
>
> 2.Prepare the request. The primary property of a request is its URI. Request headers may also include metadata such as credentials, preferred content types, and session cookies.
>
> 3.Optionally upload a request body. Instances must be configured with setDoOutput(true) if they include a request body. Transmit data by writing to the stream returned by getOutputStream().
>
> 4.Read the response. Response headers typically include metadata such as the response body's content type and length, modified dates and session cookies. The response body may be read from the stream returned by getInputStream(). If the response has no body, that method returns an empty stream.
>
> 5.Disconnect. Once the response body has been read, the HttpURLConnection should be closed by calling disconnect(). Disconnecting releases the resources held by a connection so they may be closed or reused.

Comment: Thank you so much Remy. I appreciate it. Do you know where I could find a template to learn from on how to insert that into my code under each button listener?

Comment: I see, just saw the update. I'll trying playing with this and see if it works:  URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }